# How to load scss files globally.?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, ionic4

I am facing issues while loading scss in Angular/Ionic application. Could someone explain in which order the Application loads the scss files (is it in angular.json file mentioned order ).?

Comment: what's your issue exactly? Be more specific and provide example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is using order from angular.json.
This is setup for less, but with scss rules are the same.
angular.json
[image]
resulting styles bundle (style.js file)
[image]